# Apply non-standard css style properties at run time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, outlook

In order to solve unwanted gap in Outlook, I'm trying to add style properties:
`mso-table-lspace:0pt !important;mso-table-rspace:0pt !important;` to table elements.
I've tried the following:

```
- $(element).css('mso-table-lspace', '0pt');
- element.style.setProperty('mso-table-lspace', '0pt');
- element.setAttribute('style', 'mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;');
- var sheet = document.createElement('style')
  sheet.innerHTML = "table {mso-table-lspace:0pt !important;mso-table-rspace:0pt !important;}";
  var firstEl = document.body.firstChild;
  document.body.insertBefore(sheet, firstEl)
- element.style.msoTableLspace = "0pt";
```

but nothing affects the resulted html. The properties are not added to the tables style. I would appreciate help.

Comment: Outlook ? I presume you're building emails ? If so, how is JavaScript going to help ? Post up some code and we can have a looky...

Comment: I'm sending the html to Outlook. The html is built using JavaScript. The above code is showing what I've tried to do. Is there something special I need to implement/add when adding non-standard css style properties at runtime? Many thanks, PS.

Comment: First of all, for emails, CSS should really be inline as opposed to in a <style> tag in the <head>. I'd try adding the inline styles to the appropriate elements as they're being output from the javascript...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. My element is <table>, but the 'mso-table-lspace/rspace' are not added to the table style. For example, after: $(element).css('mso-table-lspace', '0pt'); $(element).css('mso-table-lspace'); is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old post, but I'm attempting to do the same thing, except I'm trying to read these CSS properties, so I'll leave it written for future reference.

The `mso- *` properties are not standard HTML, but [proprietary to Microsoft Office](https://gist.github.com/p3t3r67x0/ac9d052595b406d5a5c1), so they cannot be written or read using `element.style` or via jQuery `$(element).css()` (which internally relies on `element.style`).

The only way to handle them (which seems to work now) is to directly manipulate the style attribute string like so:

```
var style = element.getAttribute("style");
if (style !== null) {
    style = style.trim();
    if (style.length > 0 && style.substr(-1) !== ";")
        style += "; ";
} else
    style = "";

element.setAttribute("style", style + "mso-table-lspace: 0pt;");
```

If you just need to add them, and you know they aren't there already, you can append them without the need to parse the contents of the style attribute.

Tested on:

- Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- FireFox 91.0.1 (64-bit)
- Microsoft Edge Version 92.0.902.67 (Official Build) (64 bit)
- Internet Explorer Version 20H2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping there would be a cleaner way but that's it. I would however add before that `setAttribute` line a check to see if the style ends with a `;` and add it if it doesn't

Comment: @KiJéy, you are right about te `;`, I edit my answer.